# Почему не работает парсинг?

Tags: python, lxml, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Уважаемые, всю голову сломал. Вдруг в BeautifulSoup перестал работать парсинг сайта. Я решил, что это знак и переписал код под новый для меня lxml, но и он не находит нужного. Грешил на то, что поломали html, пробовал soupparser, но это ничего не даёт. Просто выдаётся пустой список.

Нужно: для начала - текст подписи к tumbnail (в тегах `<p>`)

```
import urllib
import lxml.html.soupparser

url = 'http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/journal/wallpaper'

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
root = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(url)
print root.xpath(
        '/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/p[2]/')
```

Пробовал ещё искать `//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/p[2]/` с тем же результатом

Что я тут делаю не так? Или это сайта баг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

url = 'http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/journal/wallpaper'

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
print doc.xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr/td/div/p[2]')
```

Вы наверное копировали xpath из браузера? Браузеры добавляют в таблицу tbody, потому что так положено, а в коде этого тега нету

Comment: Спасибо! Всё верно, xpath брал из браузеров. 
А как вы получили xpath из этой каши? Неужели вручную?

Comment: нет, взял ваш и выкинул tbody =)

Comment: //*[@id="content"]/table/tr/td/div/p[2]

это наверное более правильный будет